# Submit a revised manuscript to another journal

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript to a journal. After submitting it, I found mistakes in the manuscript and corrected them. I tried to send the revised version of the manuscript to the journal, but it is not available. I tried to withdraw the manuscript, but that seems impossible too. Under this situation, is it appropriate to submit the revised version of the manuscript to another journal?

I am not sure if the original manuscript is under review since the status is "submitted to the journal" for a long time.

Comment: While @Allure's answer is the right one, I still have one question. What kind of mistakes did you find? It's a different scenario whether they were some typos you corrected, some missed references you fixed or if you accidentally accepted the main hypothesis while the data suggested otherwise.

Comment: @Jeroen The proof is not complete(This is a math paper).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is down completely to the lack of response from the first journal. Therefore you should contact them (I would contact the publisher, not the editorial board). Tell them what you have written in the question and see what they say. It's fairly straightforward for them to withdraw your paper so I would assume that's what they will do.

You could add something to the tune of "if I don't hear from you in the next ___ weeks I will submit to another journal", if they don't respond.

Do not submit to another journal until you have made a real attempt to resolve the situation with the first journal - it would be duplicate submission in that case.

Answer (score 3):

It is your right to simply withdraw the paper by giving notice. The copyright is still yours and they have no rights to it at all. You don't really require a response. Tell them unequivocally that you withdraw the paper from all future consideration. You don't need to give them "deadlines" for a reply.

They have no right even to string you along by not replying. That is their poor process. Being "under review" makes no difference in your ownership.

Once you do that you are free to submit it elsewhere. But don't submit until you make the withdrawal final.

---

Note that I can't judge whether you are doing the right thing by withdrawing or would be better off waiting. And you don't say how long this has been since first submission. But as long as you still hold copyright, you hold all rights.